# How to join two dataframes where key to be used for joining has different datatype in both dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have two dataframes df1, df2 whose schema is as follows:

DF1 is of the form:

```
slotSize2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 120x600: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pView: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 160x600: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pATF: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pView: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pViewV1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sPos: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 250x250: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pView: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 300x250: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- level: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pATF: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pView: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pViewV1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sPos: string (nullable = true)
```

Dataframe df2  has schema :

```
root
 |-- bidId: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- slotSize1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

In dataframe df2 we have slotSize (named as slotSize1) in form of string and in dataframe df1 we have nested form of slotsize i.e. for every slotsize we have corresponding map.

I want to join two dataframes df1, df2 to form a new dataframe df3 which has schema (bidId, slotSize , viewMap) where bidId is present in df1 , slotSIze is of form 120x600  and is present in both schemas, and viewMap corresponds to the nested map corresponding to every slotSize in df1.

Comment: what  you have tried so far which is not working or which is working ?

Comment: I tried joining data frames using                                                           "df1.join(df2, $"slotSize2" === $"slotSize1", "outer")"   but this failed as datatype of slotsize2 in df1 and slotsize1 in df2 is not same

Comment: How should it even work? `slotSize1` is a array of strings. What it suppose to match?

Comment: Yes i know that it won't work this way ......I want to know if somehow the following thing can be done : "Generate a new table from these two tables which have three columns bidId, slotSize and vmap(which corresonds to map of each slotsize in df1 ) .